# Dynamic variables in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I'd like to know what is the exact code for dynamic variable from link and have it set via conditions of If and If else.

let say i have link of **default.asp?variable=value&string=number**

how can i get this into my page with coding it in conditional term. (not sure if my code is correct)

```
<%
DIM value = something
If blah-blah then
 [asp code here]
else if blah-blah then
 [another asp code here]
end if
%>
```

i have to match a dynamic value on If and Else If, something like that.
thanks in advance...

Comment: Your description says php but your question title and tags indicate asp classic, which one is it? (edit: I might have misinterpreted what you're trying to do actually!)

Comment: yeah, sorry about that, i overlooked at it.

Comment: err... what exactly do you want it to do?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume your question is about ASP classic and that you're going to handle:

- default.asp?cmd=add&x=5&y=4
- default.asp?cmd=mult&x=5&y=4

And, respectively, you want the outputs to be

- Answer is 9
- Answer is 20

The ASP for that would be something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>simple asp</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
Dim cmd, x, y
cmd = Request.QueryString("cmd")
x = CDbl(Request.QueryString("x"))
y = CDbl(Request.QueryString("y"))
Select Case cmd
Case "add"
  Response.Write("Answer is " & (x + y))
Case "mult"
  Response.Write("Answer is " & (x * y))
Case Else
  Response.Write("Please supply a valid cmd")
End Select
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

get idea from this line of codes

```
<%
Set udrmcatgry=TheDB.Execute("SELECT * FROM rmcatgry ORDER BY sl asc")
Do while Not udrmcatgry.eof=true 
myqsl=udrmcatgry("sl")
TheDB.Execute "Update `rmcatgry` set   catnme`='"&request.form(""+myqsl+"")&"' where sl='"&myqsl&"' "
udrmcatgry.MoveNext         
Loop
%>
```